# Calculate averages to display in center of d3 donut chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICvmNoe2FKxasEp66psV?p=preview) where i am using angularjs and d3.js.

I am generating a few donut charts here i would like to know how to display the average of the data in the middle of the arc instead of the percentage. Also how would i display the labels on the arcs

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "inside")
        .text(function(d) { 
            return '56%'; 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right now that percentage is obviously hard-coded in.  To replace that hard-coded percentage with the data's average, you'd need to replace the `56%` with the data's average.

Since the array of data used to calculate each donut chart is readily available as `data` (originally `scope.data`), you could do this to display the average:

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "inside")
        .text(function(d) { 
            return data.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b } )/data.length;
        });
```

Also, as Henry pointed out in the comments, a more straight-forward way would be to simply use `d3.mean` in place of my reduce function over the array length.  So in place of that line, you'd simply put:

```
            return d3.mean(data);
```

You can see the result [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M0k87XhQ8DQyHjUPqaqR?p=preview).

Any browser that supports d3 should also support the ECMA5 reduce method I used here, but if you plan on using this with a d3 shim like r2d3 to try for IE8 support, you should include a `Array.prototype.reduce` polyfill [like this one from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

The question about the labels is properly another question (as you may know, StackOverflow wants only one question per post). Ask that as another question, and I'll be happy to take a look as soon we finish up with this one.

Comment: You could also use `.text(function(d) { return d3.mean(data); });` as another way to get the mean

Comment: Excellent point, Henry.  I sometimes forget that d3 has all these useful utility functions.